# Update specific column within the same table and add limit - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to update the value of a column within the same table by transforming its former value, but I would like to first test it with the first 10 data according to its created date.

I am getting this error though

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 6: limit 10
```

Here is my sample code:

```
UPDATE posts p1
SET cooked = (select entity2char(strip_tags(p2.cooked))
FROM posts p2
WHERE p1.id = p2.id
ORDER BY p2.created_at ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Any syntax that would make this work?

Comment: What is `entity2char()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's just a function to transform the data into a formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I don't see why you are using a self-join.  If you just want to delete the top 10 entities, you can use:

```
UPDATE posts p
    SET cooked = entity2char(strip_tags(p.cooked))
    WHERE p.id IN (SELECT p2.id
                   FROM posts p2
                   ORDER BY p2.created_at ASC 
                   LIMIT 10
                  );
```

Comment: I'm testing this code now and it seems that it's still running. The real data from the `posts` table is about millions.

Comment: @illumillukilluallukalluto . . . Kill the code!  The `FROM` clause should not have been in the query.

Comment: Killed it already. Should I stick to my previous syntax instead?

Comment: @illumillukilluallukalluto . . . No.  I fixed the query.  It shouldn't have a `FROM` clause.  That is the point of this version.

Comment: Yeah, the one I ran earlier that was running endlessly was the one you shared. Maybe the one causing the slowness is the `ORDER` clause?

Comment: @illumillukilluallukalluto . . .It had a `FROM` clause which is now removed.  That is why it did not complete.

Comment: I see! Didn't notice that. Thank you for this. It works!